# How to do multivariate regression in R?

Tags: r, self-study, multivariate-regression

I need to preform a multivariate normal regression in R. The question is:

> Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$, and $Y_3$ follows multivariate normal distribution. What is
>
> 1. the conditional of $Y_3$ given $Y_1$ and $Y_2$
> 2. the conditional of $Y_2$ given $Y_1$
>
>    From these two, derive:
> 3. the joint distribution of $Y_3$ and $Y_2$ given $Y_1$.

Now suppose you have a sample of size $n$ from the multivariate normal distribution. Do the two regressions in (1) and (2). **How can I combine them to get (3), the regression of $Y_3$ and $Y_2$ on $Y_1$?**

```
library(mvtnorm)
mu  <- c(1,2,3)
Sig <- matrix(c(4,2,1,2,4,-1,1,-1,4), nrow=3, ncol=3) 
Y   <- rmvnorm(20, mean=mu, sigma=Sig) #generate multivariate normal distribution
y3  <- lm(Y[,3]~Y[,1] + Y[,2]) 
y2  <- lm(Y[,2]~Y[,1])
```

Comment: I added the `self-study` tag to your question, since this is a homework/self-study question. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: Does the bold question the only one ? I think it is just an application of the preliminary question (the theoretical one about multivariate normal distributions) by substituting the true parameters with their estimates.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
set.seed(12345)
library(mvtnorm)
mu  <- c(1,2,3)
Sig <- matrix(c(4,2,1,2,4,-1,1,-1,4), nrow=3, ncol=3)
Y   <- rmvnorm(20, mean=mu, sigma=Sig) #generate multivariate normal distribution
y3  <- lm(Y[,3]~Y[,1] + Y[,2])
y2  <- lm(Y[,2]~Y[,1])
Y23 <- lm(cbind(Y[,2], Y[,3])~Y[,1])
summary(Y23)
anova(Y23)
```

**Output**

```
summary(Y23)
Response Y[, 2] :

Call:
lm(formula = `Y[, 2]` ~ Y[, 1])

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.0151 -1.1028 -0.2606  0.9836  4.1341 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   2.1441     0.7060   3.037  0.00709 **
Y[, 1]        0.3161     0.2780   1.137  0.27049   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.137 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.067,     Adjusted R-squared:  0.01516 
F-statistic: 1.293 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.2705


Response Y[, 3] :

Call:
lm(formula = `Y[, 3]` ~ Y[, 1])

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.1493 -1.2435 -0.1305  1.5748  4.3708 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   2.4869     0.8722   2.851   0.0106 *
Y[, 1]        0.2232     0.3435   0.650   0.5241  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.64 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.02292,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.03137 
F-statistic: 0.4222 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.5241


> anova(Y23)
Analysis of Variance Table

            Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)  1 0.88361   64.533      2     17 1.149e-08 ***
Y[, 1]       1 0.17884    1.851      2     17    0.1873    
Residuals   18                                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation concerning how this answers the question?  What specifically are you proposing as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on the answer above, if you are interested in the multivariate regression of $(y_2, y_3)$ on $y_1$, we can show using properties of the multivariate normal distribution that this is equivalent to the univariate regressions of $y_2$ on $y_1$ and of $y_3$ on $y_1$.

Let $Y = (y_1, y_2, y_3)^T \sim N\left((\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3)^T,\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\sigma_1^2 & \sigma_{12} & \sigma_{13} \\ \sigma_{12} & \sigma_2^2 & \sigma_{23} \\ \sigma_{13} & \sigma_{23} & \sigma_3^2 \end{array} \right) \right)$.

By properties of the multivariate normal distribution, the joint regression of $y_2, y_3$ on $y_1$ is $E((y_2,y_3)^T|y_1) = (\mu_2,\mu_3)^T +  (\sigma_{12}, \sigma_{13})^T \frac{y_1 - \mu_1}{\sigma_1^2}$. After a little additional algebra, we can show that this reduces to a 2x1 vector of the univariate regressions of $y_3$ and $y_2$ respectively on $y_1$.

Therefore as shown above by the previous answer, it is sufficient to regress each of $y_3$ and $y_2$ on $y_1$ individually to get the joint regression.